# Local storage issue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm working on an e-commerce site in React. I have a "Quantity" component, and I'm trying to get the quantity values to persist on the "Products" page after a user increases and/or decreases the quantities. I am doing this through local storage, but when I refresh the page, the value in local storage is updated on the first product only, and not the product for which I updated the quantity initially. Here's my "Quantity" component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Quantity({
  counter,
  setCounter,
  inventory,
  handleCounterDecrease,
  handleCounterIncrease,
}) {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(0);
  const [inventoryWarning, setInventoryWarning] = useState("");

  function increaseQuantity() {
    setQuantity((quantity) => quantity + 1);
    handleCounterIncrease();
    if (inventory === quantity) {
      setInventoryWarning("Quantity exceeds stock levels.");
      setQuantity(quantity);
      setCounter(counter);
    }
  }

  function decreaseQuantity() {
    setInventoryWarning("");
    handleCounterDecrease();
    setQuantity((quantity) => quantity - 1);
    if (quantity < 1) {
      setQuantity(0);
      setCounter(counter);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quantity"));
    if (data) {
      setQuantity(data);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("quantity", JSON.stringify(quantity));
  }, [quantity]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="cart-quantity-container">
        <i onClick={decreaseQuantity} class="minus square icon"></i>
        <span>Quantity: {quantity}</span>
        <i onClick={increaseQuantity} class="plus square icon"></i>
        <p>{inventoryWarning}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Quantity;
```

Comment: You always use the same key (`"quantity"`) to store data to and read data from local storage. You might want to make the key dynamic, e.g. with a product ID.

Comment: Can you show the object you are attempting to store in the localStorage quantity?